# how to insert form data into database in moodle

Tags: database, insert, moodle

I have created a simple form in the NEWMODULE plugin and a  database table to save form data, but i don't know how to insert the form data into the database. I save the code into my_form.php, this is my code:

```
class myform_form extends moodleform {

public function definition() {
    global $DB,$CFG;

    $mform = &$this->_form;
    $mform->addElement('text', 'tendethi', get_string('tendethi', 'myform'));
    $mform->setType('tendethi', PARAM_TEXT);
    $mform->setDefault('tendethi','Nhập tên đề thi');
    $mform->addElement('text', 'mdt', get_string('madethi','myform'));
    $mform->setType('mdt', PARAM_TEXT);
    $mform->setDefault('mdt','Nhập mã đề thi');
    $mform->addElement('duration', 'timelimit', get_string('thoigianlambai','myform'));
    $mform->setType('timelimit', PARAM_TEXT);
    $mform->addElement('text', 'gvrd', get_string('giaovienrade','myform'));
    $mform->setType('gvrd', PARAM_TEXT);
    $mform->setDefault('gvrd','Nhập họ tên giáo viên ra đề thi');
    $mform->addElement('text', 'tmh', get_string('tenmonhoc','myform'));
    $mform->setType('tmh', PARAM_TEXT);
    $mform->setDefault('tmh','Nhập tên môn học');

    $buttonarray=array();
    $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('submit', 'submitbutton', get_string('savechanges'));
    $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('reset', 'resetbutton', get_string('revert'));
    $buttonarray[] = &$mform->createElement('cancel');
    $mform->addGroup($buttonarray, 'buttonar', '', array(' '), false);
    $mform->closeHeaderBefore('buttonar');
```

and this is code insert form data into database :

```
// insert database into table
//global $DB;
$tendethi = optional_param('tendethi', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$mdt = optional_param('mdt', null, PARAM_INT);
$timelimit = optional_param('timelimit', null, PARAM_INT);
$gvrd = optional_param('gvrd', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$tmh = optional_param('tmh', null, PARAM_TEXT);
if($data = $mform->get_data()){
$record = new stdClass();
$record->tendethi = $tendethi ;
$record->mdt = $mdt ;
$record->timelimit = $timelimit ;
$record->gvrd = $gvrd ;
$record->tmh = $tmh ;
$DB=insert_record('myform_form', $record, false);
```

}

please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look roughly like this:

```
$urlaftersubmission = new moodle_url(); // You will need to fill this in.
$form = new myform_form();
if ($form->is_cancelled()) {
    redirect($urlaftersubmission);
}
if ($data = $form->get_data()) {
    $DB->insert_record('name_of_table', $data);
    redirect($urlaftersubmission);
}
echo $OUTPUT->header();
$form->display();
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Note, you may have to adjust the data slightly for it to be in the correct format for inserting in the database. You should also make sure that you create your database table using the install.xml or upgrade.php files in your plugin (and use the Moodle built-in xmldb editor to generate those files correctly), otherwise Moodle will not recognise them for inserting data.

Comment: thank you very much, i've crated a table by xmldb to store data, i tried to fill in my form and click save button but its error, this is an error : 
line 857 of \lib\deprecatedlib.php: coding_exception thrown
line 56 of \mod\myform\view.php: call to error() <div class="notifytiny debuggingmessage" data-rel="debugging">Invalid array parameter detected in required_param(): timelimit<ul style="text-align: left" data-rel="backtrace"><li>line 641 of \lib\moodlelib.php: call to debugging()</li><li>line 40 of \mod\myform\view.php: call to optional_param()</li></ul></div>

Comment: I'm not clear why you are calling optional_param - if you want the data from the form, call get_data() (as you are already doing and as I have shown above), there is no reason to call optional_param as well (especially as that will not format the 'duration' field into a timestamp).

Comment: thank you very so much, i've inserted and selected the database. After inserting data, i will show information table data has inserted, i want to create edit and delete button in this table, next to the data lines in table, how should i do? can you help me? thank you very much.